# How to get Log4Perl to use separate files for each script?

Tags: perl

In the [FAQ](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.33/lib/Log/Log4perl/FAQ.pm#I_want_to_log_ERROR_and_WARN_messages_to_different_files!_How_can_I_do_that?) for Log4perl it is explained how to write the config file to use separate files for ERROR and INFO.

This works great for one script or if one wants to mix several scripts ERROR and INFO into 
the same ERROR and INFO logs.

**Question**

I would very much like each script have its own ERROR and INFO files, and that I still are able to just use

```
$logger->info()
$logger->error()
```

Have I made `log.conf` correct?

And how should I initiate Log4perl in each script?

**account.pl**

```
use Log::Log4perl;
Log::Log4perl::init('log.conf');
my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger('????');
```

**log.conf**

```
log4perl.logger.account = INFO, AccountErrorLogFile, AccountInfoLogFile, AccountInfoLogFile, SystemErrorLogFile, testScreen

# Filter to match level ERROR
log4perl.filter.MatchError = Log::Log4perl::Filter::LevelMatch
log4perl.filter.MatchError.LevelToMatch  = ERROR
log4perl.filter.MatchError.AcceptOnMatch = true

# Filter to match level INFO
log4perl.filter.MatchInfo  = Log::Log4perl::Filter::LevelMatch
log4perl.filter.MatchInfo.LevelToMatch  = INFO
log4perl.filter.MatchInfo.AcceptOnMatch = true

# Error appender
log4perl.appender.AccountErrorLogFile                          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.AccountErrorLogFile.filename                 = /logs/error--account-pl.log
log4perl.appender.AccountErrorLogFile.layout                   = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.AccountErrorLogFile.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%3L] %m%n
log4perl.appender.AccountErrorLogFile.Filter                   = MatchError

# Info appender
log4perl.appender.AccountInfoLogFile                          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.AccountInfoLogFile.filename                 = /logs/info--account-pl.log
log4perl.appender.AccountInfoLogFile.layout                   = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.AccountInfoLogFile.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%3L] %m%n
log4perl.appender.AccountInfoLogFile.Filter                   = MatchInfo

# Error appender
log4perl.appender.SystemErrorLogFile                          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.SystemErrorLogFile.filename                 = /logs/error--system-pl.log
log4perl.appender.SystemErrorLogFile.layout                   = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.SystemErrorLogFile.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%3L] %m%n
log4perl.appender.SystemErrorLogFile.Filter                   = MatchError

# Info appender
log4perl.appender.SystemInfoLogFile                          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.SystemInfoLogFile.filename                 = /logs/info--system-pl.log
log4perl.appender.SystemInfoLogFile.layout                   = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.SystemInfoLogFile.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%3L] %m%n
log4perl.appender.SystemInfoLogFile.Filter                   = MatchInfo

# Development Appender
log4perl.appender.testScreen                          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen
log4perl.appender.testScreen.stderr                   = 0
log4perl.appender.testScreen.layout                   = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.testScreen.layout.ConversionPattern = %-5p [%3L] %m%n
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:

**log.conf**

```
log4perl.logger.account = INFO, AccountErrorLogFile, AccountInfoLogFile, testScreen
log4perl.logger.system  = INFO, SystemErrorLogFile, SystemInfoLogFile, testScreen
```

**account.pl**

```
Log::Log4perl::init('/var/www/useradmin/cgi-bin/log.conf');
my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger('account');
```

**system.pl**

```
Log::Log4perl::init('/var/www/useradmin/cgi-bin/log.conf');
my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger('system');
```

Comment: You can simply use `$ARGV` to get the name of the script: `(my $script = $ARGV) =~ s|\.pl||; my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger( $script );`

Comment: In Perl the name of the script is in `$0`, not `$ARGV`. Also you'll likely need to get just its basename, `basename($0)`.